# How do I reproduce checksum of gzip files copied with s3DistCp (from Google Cloud Storage to AWS S3)

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, gzip, checksum, s3distcp

I copied a large number of gzip files from Google Cloud Storage to AWS's S3 using s3DistCp (as [this AWS article](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/big-data/copy-large-datasets-from-google-cloud-storage-to-amazon-s3-using-amazon-emr/) describes). When I try to compare the files' checksums, they differ (md5/sha-1/sha-256 have same issue).

If I compare the sizes (bytes) or the decompressed contents of a few files (`diff` or another checksum), they match. (In this case, I'm comparing files pulled directly down from Google via `gsutil` vs pulling down my distcp'd files from S3).

Using `file`, I do see a difference between the two:

```
file1-gs-direct.gz: gzip compressed data, original size modulo 2^32 91571
file1-via-s3.gz:    gzip compressed data, from FAT filesystem (MS-DOS, OS/2, NT), original size modulo 2^32 91571
```

#### My Goal/Question:

My goal is to verify that my downloaded files match the original files' checksums, but I don't want to have to re-download or analyze the files directly on Google. Is there something I can do on my s3-stored files to reproduce the original checksum?

#### Things I've tried:

***Re-gzipping with different compressions:***
While I wouldn't expect s3DistCp to change the original file's compression, here's my attempt at recompressing:

```sh
target_sha=$(shasum -a 1 file1-gs-direct.gz | awk '{print $1}')
for i in {1..9}; do
  cur_sha=$(cat file1-via-s3.gz | gunzip | gzip -n -$i | shasum -a 1 | awk '{print $1}')
  echo "$i. $target_sha == $cur_sha ? $([[ $target_sha == $cur_sha ]] && echo 'Yes' || echo 'No')"
done

1. abcd...1234 == dcba...4321 ? No
2. ... ? No
...
2. ... ? No
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While typing out my question, I figured out the answer:

S3DistCp is apparently switching the "OS" version in the gzip header, which explains the "FAT filesystem" label I'm seeing with `file`. *(Note: to rule out S3 directly causing the issue, I copied my "file1-gs-direct.gz" up to S3, and after pulling down, the checksum remains the same.)*

Here's the diff between the two files:

```sh
$ diff <(cat file1-gs-direct.gz | hexdump -C) <(cat file1-via-s3.gz | hexdump -C)
1c1
< 00000000  1f 8b 08 00 00 00 00 00  00 ff ed 7d 59 73 db 4a  |...........}Ys.J|
---
> 00000000  1f 8b 08 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 ed 7d 59 73 db 4a  |...........}Ys.J|
```

It turns out the 10th byte in a gzip file "identifies the type of file system on which compression took place" ([Gzip RFC](http://www.zlib.org/rfc-gzip.html)):

```
    +---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
    |ID1|ID2|CM |FLG|     MTIME     |XFL|OS | (more-->)
    +---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
```

Using `hexedit`, I'm able to change my "via-s3" file's OS from `00` to `FF` and then the checksums match.

***Caveat:*** Editing this on a file that is later decompressed may cause unexpected issues, so use with caution.  (In my case, I'm doing a file checksum, so worse case a file shows as mismatching even when the uncompressed contents remained the same).